# Hadoop2: Is it possible to recover namenode state only from QJM?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, disaster-recovery

I'm trying to simulate scenarios where some physical servers of my hadoop cluster go down and I have to deploy new ones.

From what I understand in the documentation, there's no way to configure more than 2 namenodes running at once (one active and one in standby mode).

Is there a way to recover all the namenode's metadata if those 2 servers were going down irrecoverably at once?

I understand this is an unlikely scenario, but maybe there is something that can be done in this situation through the QJM.